# Does modus tollens capture the essence of "necessary condition"?

Tags: logic, intuition, necessity

Does modus tollens capture the essence of "necessary condition"?

(1) P → Q, ¬Q, … so ¬P.

(2) So Q is a necessary condition of P.

Is (1) the inner structure of (2)?

Are any of these true:

The sense of "necessary condition" means carrying out *modus tollens* in the imagination.

Seeing how "the absence of Q unravels P" is the source of the sense of "necessary condition."

To evoke the sense of NC, we must carry out an act of *modus tollens* perhaps with a minimal degree of intentionality and distinctness.

Comment: **P → Q** is "Q is a necessary condition for P".

Comment: I wouldn't say carrying out *modus tollens* in the imagination is a necessary condition for understanding "necessary condition" (pun intended). But there is something to *modus ponens* standing for sufficiency and *modus tollens* for necessity as a heuristic association. Although you can equally associate P → Q to necessity and Q → P to sufficiency (of Q for P), and get by without negations and *modus tollens* altogether.